# Why doesn't this simple enable_if work?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having a problem with an `enable_if` construct which I've managed to reduce to a very simple piece of failing code:

```
template <typename Enable, typename...Args>                                 
struct Get;                                                     

template <typename FirstArg, typename... OtherArgs>                       
struct Get<typename std::enable_if<true>::type, FirstArg, OtherArgs...>
{                                                                               
    using type = FirstArg;                                                          
};
```

([Live example](http://ideone.com/RAppHv))

The above code is a gutted version of some code that did something useful, but for the sake of this question I'm more interested in *why* this doesn't work, not whether or not it's ideal or does anything useful. The meta function `Get` *should* take the first type passed to it and, based on some condition (in this case always true as I didn't construct a case for when it is not) return it.

I *don't* want the first argument to resolve to the `enable_if` condition, that should be completely abstracted.

When I try to run this (see live example) it produces

> error: ‘type’ in ‘struct Get’ does not name a type   using T =
>   typename Get::type

Why?

Comment: You didn't provide the second template parameter for `enable_if`. By default it is `void`.

Comment: @user657267 that's the idea..

Comment: @quant But in your live example, you've provided `int` as the first template argument. `int != void`, so the specialization won't match.

Comment: You also don't need `typename` in both cases.

Comment: @dyp Ok, but I'm not trying to match `int`, I want to enable that particular specialisation if `true` is `true`, and I want the first argument to resolve to `FirstArg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specialization you wrote only kicks in if someone passed `void` as the first argument to `Get`.

In your example code, you passed `int`.  So the specialization does not apply.

The names of the types in the template definition and specialization have no connection, just their position in the `Get<blah, blah, blah>`.  And it is pattern matching off the primary definition.

```
int main() {
  using T = Get<void, int>::type;
}
```

Comment: Ok, clearly I don't understand templates as well as I should. How would I write the above program to enable the specialisation iff `true` is "true" (in `enable_if`) but still only return the _first_ argument?

Comment: @quant Add a layer of indirection.

Comment: @dyp could you elaborate? Do you mean like a `GetImpl` class which is given `void` from `Get`?

Comment: @quant Yes. For example, `template<typename... Args> using another_layer_of_indirection = Get<void, Args...>;` It is also possible to group the arguments in a type list (e.g. tuple) and put the dummy parameter after the arguments, this way you can specify a default argument.

Comment: @quant You eliminated things that matter from your question.  Make a new question asking your real problem.  `true` is always true, so...

Comment: @Yakk I've posted a new question that provides a working example of the exercise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447026/how-do-i-enable-if-a-struct-depending-on-a-condition-and-how-many-arguments