# How do I enable_if a struct depending on a condition and how many arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a meta function that returns a certain type if more than 1 argument is passed to it, and another type based on a condition if only a single argument is passed to it. The condition is arbitrary so it will require an `enable_if` or something of that kind, but for this example I'll just make it a type comparison. Let's simplify it to the following

1. If a single argument is passed and that argument is an `int`, return `bool`
2. If a single argument is passed and that argument is a `double`, return `int`
3. If more than 1 argument is passed, return `double`

To achieve this I have tried to do the following:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Enable, typename...Args>                                 
struct Get;                                                     

// multiple arguments; return double regardless of the condition
template <typename FirstArg, typename... OtherArgs>                       
struct Get<typename std::enable_if<true>::type, FirstArg, OtherArgs...>
{                                                                               
    using type = double;
};

// single int; return bool
template <typename Arg>                       
struct Get<typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Arg, int>::value>::type, Arg>
{
    using type = double;
};

// single double; return int
template <typename Arg>
struct Get<typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Arg, double>::value>::type, Arg>
{
    using type = int;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Get<double>::type, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Get<int>::type, bool>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename Get<bool, int>::type, double>::value, "");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> prog.cpp:29:51: error: ‘type’ in ‘struct Get<double>’ does not name a type
>   static_assert(std::is_same<typename Get<double>::type, int>::value, "");
>                                                    ^
> prog.cpp:29:60: error: template argument 1 is invalid
>   static_assert(std::is_same<typename Get<double>::type, int>::value, "");
> ```

I would be grateful for an answer that teaches me *why* this doesn't work the way I expected, not just how to fix it. I'm struggling to find good resources on template meta-programming and have so far been programming rather haphazardly, which is something I'd very much like to fix!

[Live example here](http://ideone.com/BjHaoN)

Comment: What you need is this [webpage](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html)

Comment: You don't need `enable_if` here at all: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79314b2d15824360 (the more-than-one argument specialization could actually be a `static_assert` in the primary template).

Comment: @dyp I was trying to create a simplified example, the `enable_if` should represent any arbitrary condition. I've edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Even then, I'm not sure if you need `enable_if` itself; you could as well match the condition (as a type function) with a template parameter defaulted to `std::true_type`. (One could argue that using `enable_if` is clearer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `template` arguments to a specialization are not the template arguments to the original definition.

The ones that correspond to the original definition are after the `template` name.

The arguments in the `template<>` part of the specialization are the types introduced to match the specialization.

So original definition:

```
template <typename Enable, typename...Args>                                 
struct Get;
```

1 or more type arguments.  And, unless a specialization matches, not defined.

First specialization:

```
template <typename FirstArg, typename... OtherArgs>                       
struct Get<typename std::enable_if<true>::type, FirstArg, OtherArgs...> {                                                                               
  using type = double;
};
```

well, `std::enable_if<true>::type` is just `void`, so this is the same as:

```
template <typename FirstArg, typename... OtherArgs>                       
struct Get<void, FirstArg, OtherArgs...> {                                                                               
  using type = double;
};
```

So this matches if the first type is `void`, and there is at least one other type.

Second specialization:

```
template <typename Arg>                       
struct Get<typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Arg, int>::value>::type, Arg> {
  using type = double;
};
```

So this tries to match if there are two types.  The second one is pattern matched.

If it isn't `int`, the first one SFINAE fails.  If it is an `int`, the first one ends up being `void`.  So this matches `Get<void, int>` only.

Third specialization:

```
template <typename Arg>
struct Get<typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Arg, double>::value>::type, Arg> {
  using type = int;
};
```

similarly, this matches `Get<void, double>`.

Specialization is pattern matching.  SFINAE `enable_if` clauses cannot be pattern matched.  So the pattern match runs, then the `enable_if` clauses are evaluated.  If they fail, the specialization does not match.  If they succeed, the `enable_if` clause produces a type.  After all types are generated (pattern and not), the resulting list of types either matches or does not.

The easy ways to use this machinery include having your public version forward to a details one, passing `void` as the first type, and doing your `enable_if` work there.

Another way is to bundle your types up into a list of types, like `template<class...>struct types{};`, and pass that as one argument, and `void` as the second argument, and do SFINAE again on that `void`.

Here is an example:

```
namespace details {
  template<class...>struct types{};
  template<class Types, class=void>
  struct foo;
  template<class T0, class... Ts>
  struct foo<types<T0, Ts...>,typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T0, int>::value && (sizeof...(Ts)>=1)
  >> {
    using type=double;
  };
}
template<class T0, class... Ts>
struct foo:details::foo< details::types<T0, Ts...> >{};
```

The specialization of `details::foo` pattern matches the `types` bundle.  It does the `enable_if` logic with those pattern matched types.  The `enable_if` passes if and only if the first type is an `int` and there are 1 or more additional types (for an arbitrary set of tests).